# Is there any efficient way to write this code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I want to write this code in python.

```
proc sql;
select count(distinct ID_1)
from DATA
where ID_1 = ID_2 and ID_type in ("11","23","46");
quit;
```

I can do this in three steps

```
a = [x if x==y and z in ("11","23", "46") for x,y,z in zip(DATA['x'],DATA['y'],DATA['z'])]
a = [i for i in a if str(i) != 'nan']
len(np.unique(a))
```

Is there any efficient way to write the same code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most common SQL operations can be easily translated in python and pandas:

```
DATA[(DATA.ID_1 == DATA.ID_2) & (DATA.ID_type.isin(["11", "23", "46"]))].ID_1.nunique()
```

Read the [introduction to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

A different take filtering using `query` method:

```
DATA.query('ID_1 == ID_2 and ID_type.isin(["11", "23", "46"])').ID_1.nunique()
```

Comment: i'm not entirely sure u can use ```isin``` can be used within ```query```. maybe ```in``` instead?

Comment: You can use some of the series methods in query, like `isin`, `isnull()` isn't that great?

Comment: oh cool. i knew about isnull, wasnt sure about isin. thanks mate

Comment: its showing error TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'